# Accessing Cooja Motes from the Remote Hosts

Tags: browser, iot, ping, contiki, cooja

I am simulating in Cooja using InstantContiki3.0 in VMware. At current, I am able to ping border-router/motes from the local host and access them locally in the browser too. However, I interested in accessing border-router/motes globally. Any suggestion/solution to ping/access local Cooja motes from the outside(remote) hosts would be highly appreciated...?

Comment: There is nothing Cooja specific here. If you know how to make a local physical network accessible remotely, it's the same thing here. The border router will serve as the node bridging or routing between the two networks (local and remote one).

Comment: @kfx Firstly thank you for your time to comment. Yes, Border Router (BR) serves as a gateway between the local network and remote. When I try to access BR from the InstantContiki browser, then it is accessible. However, accessing BR from windows browser does not work. To me, this question is Cooja specific because Cooja is a simulator for IoT which can be accessed from anywhere on the internet. Doing so requires some documentation in support of global access of IoT which may be included in Cooja. Can you suggest any such mechanism of global access...?

Comment: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html

Comment: @kfx, so nice of you...